# Calls to lstrlenA or lstrlenW are returning unexpected values

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

**Summary:** In Excel VBA, I've got a function that gets CF_TEXT from the clipboard, and another function for CF_UNICODETEXT. I use `lstrlenA` / `lstrlenW` to get the length of the string, but I'm getting unexpected results from those calls. I'd like help to understand why.

**Details:**

Within my functions, I use `CopyMemory` after opening the clipboard to get a byte array that I can then turn into a string. I'm in the process of adapting the project for 64-bit Office, and wanted to make sure everything involving `CopyMemory` is working correctly. That got me testing these clipboard functions, which is how I encountered this issue.

Before calling `CopyMemory`, I'm calling `lstrlenA(pMem)` / `lstrlenW(pMem)` to determine how much to copy. But these calls are returning unexpected lengths.

Here's one of the functions (ignoring locales):

```
Function GetANSITextFromClipboard() As String
    Dim hClip As LongPtr, pMem As LongPtr
    Dim cbText As Integer
    Dim abRetString() As Byte
    Dim RetString As String

    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT) Then
        If OpenClipboard(0) Then
            hClip = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)
            Dim clipSize As LongPtr         'added to check on mem size vs what's reported by lstrlenW
            clipSize = GlobalSize(hClip)
            pMem = GlobalLock(hClip)
            cbText = lstrlenA(pMem)

            If cbText > 0 Then
                ReDim abRetString(0 To cbText)
                CopyMemory abRetString(0), ByVal pMem, cbText '64-bit: should be good if cbText is right
                'strip terminating null
                If abRetString(UBound(abRetString)) = 0 Then
                    ReDim Preserve abRetString(0 To UBound(abRetString) - 1)
                End If
                RetString = StrConv(abRetString, vbUnicode)
            End If
            GlobalUnlock (hClip)
            CloseClipboard
            GetANSITextFromClipboard = RetString
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

These are relevant declares for that function:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long 'returns BOOL
Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr 'returns HANDLE
Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long 'returns BOOL

Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr 'returns SIZE_T
Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr 'returns LPVOID
Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long  'returns BOOL

Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlenA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As String) As Long 'returns int

Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
    Destination As Any, _
    Source As Any, _
    ByVal length As LongPtr)
```

To test, I copy something to the clipboard then run this:

```
Private Sub TestReadClipboard()
    Dim acbfFormats() As CBFormat
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strPrompt As String
    Dim strBuffer As String

    If GetClipboardFormats(acbfFormats()) Then
        strPrompt = UBound(acbfFormats()) - LBound(acbfFormats()) + 1 & " formats:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        For i = LBound(acbfFormats()) To UBound(acbfFormats())
            strPrompt = strPrompt & acbfFormats(i).uFormat & " = " & acbfFormats(i).name _
                        & " (" & acbfFormats(i).Size & " bytes)" & vbCrLf
        Next
    Else
        strPrompt = "Formats not available."
    End If
    MsgBox strPrompt

    strPrompt = "Plain text: " & GetANSITextFromClipboard & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    strPrompt = strPrompt & "Unicode text: " & GetUnicodeTextFromClipboard & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    strPrompt = strPrompt & "Locale: " & Right("00000000" & Hex(GetClipboardLocale), 8)
    MsgBox strPrompt
End Sub
```

`CBFormat` is a custom type, and `GetClipboardFormats` is a custom function that collects details about the formats in a `CBFormat` array. In particular, `CBFormat.size` for each format is set by calling `GlobalSize()`.

At the first `MsgBox strPrompt` call, the formats I see are as expected. And the size of data for each format is as expected: **at least as long as the text I copied**. Then when I call into `GetANSITextFromClipboard`, the size seen earlier is the same as `clipSize`.

But `cbText` is consistently wrong. I've tried copying to the clipboard multiple times from different sources, and `lstrlenA` is always returning **13**. In the Unicode function, `lstrlenW` is always returning **7**.

(I don't use `clipSize` as the length to copy because then I end up with null and following garbage in the string. I could walk the byte array looking for null and then redim to that, but I shouldn't need to.)

**Question:** Why don't my calls to `lstrlenA`/`lstrlenW` work?

Comment: Can you show all the relevant code (declare, etc.)?

Comment: @SimonMourier I added the declares relevant to GetANSITextFromClipboard.

Comment: `CF_TEXT` and `CF_UNICODETEXT` are required to be null-terminated strings by definition. `CF_TEXT` uses 8bit chars, `CF_UNICODETEXT` uses 16bit chars. In practice, nobody allocates more memory than is needed to hold the null terminator. So you don't need to use `lstrlen(A|W)` at all, you already know how many bytes are available to copy from `GlobalSize()`, just subtract enough bytes for the null terminator if needed.

Comment: Note that your declaration of `lstrlenA()` is wrong. Don't use `String`, that is not an 8bit string in VBA, it is a 16bit COM `BSTR` string. You are passing it a `LongPtr` from `GlobalLock()`, so use `LongPtr` as the parameter type instead of `String`. Or else just scan the byte array manually

Comment: @RemyLebeau Actually, in many cases, the memory on the clipboard is much larger than the string. For example, in some cases, I copied a four character string, but the CF_TEXT format had 1K of memory, and the CF_UNICODETEXT format had 2K. But, of course, it's always longer than the text. So, for the time being to get things working, I copy the entire amount reported by GlobalSize into an array and then find the first null and resize the array before converting to string.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: If I'm getting CF_TEXT from the clipboard, then wouldn't ```lstrlenA``` be appropriate to get the byte array? (I convert from byte array to BSTR after that.)

Comment: @PeterConstable `lstrlenA` would be appropriate for `CF_TEXT`, yes. But not the way you have declared it

Comment: @RemyLebeau The declare I have for ```lstrlenA``` was taken from the Microsoft-provided **Win32API_PtrSafe.TXT** file that I got from [www.microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9970). But it could have bugs. So, I'll try changing ```String``` to ```LongPtr```.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Changing ```String``` to ```LongPtr``` appears like it fixes the issue. But I'm not finished testing. I'm trying copying from different sources. I copied from Word and one of the 19 formats causes a crash when I enumerate the formats and try to get details on each. Last time I stepped in, I think it was calling GetSize() for an Enhanced Metafile when it crashed Excel.

Comment: @PeterConstable that would be a new question, and should be posted separately.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OK, after restarting (who knows what was in what state), I repeated a test copying from Word, and it got through 19 formats without any issue. And your fix was confirmed in this case. So, I'll consider that the answer. I'll let you post it as an answer, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of `lstrlenA()` is wrong. Don't use `String`, that is not an 8bit string in VBA, it is a 16bit COM [`BSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr) string. Since you are passing a `LongPtr` from `GlobalLock()` to `lstrlenA()`, use `LongPtr` as the parameter type instead of `String`. Otherwise, you will just have to scan the byte array manually.